# R lidR Plot multiple LAS catalog objects on a single Leaflet plot

Tags: r, lidr

I have five `LAScatalog` objects from five different subfolders present in the same parent folder. I would like to plot them together on an interactive `Leaflet` plot using `lidR`?

Please note that I know I can copy all the files into one folder, but the files are too many and `R` cannot handle those many points even though I do have 64 GB RAM.

How can I do this?

Sample Code:

```
library(lidR)

# Import the list of LAS files in the folder
FL_LAS_List = readLAScatalog("ParentFolder/SubFolder1")
BC_LAS_List_NE = readLAScatalog("ParentFolder/SubFolder2")
BC_LAS_List_NW = readLAScatalog("ParentFolder/SubFolder3")
BC_LAS_List_SW = readLAScatalog("ParentFolder/SubFolder4")
BC_LAS_List_SE = readLAScatalog("ParentFolder/SubFolder5") 

# Plot individual LAS objects
plot(FL_LAS_List, mapview = TRUE,
     map.type = "OpenStreetMap")

# Plot all five LAS catalog objects on a single map using the above plot code
# Stuck!!!....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two options here.

##### Use only one collection

Either using

```r
rbind(FL_LAS_List, BC_LAS_List_NE, BC_LAS_List_NW, ...)
```

or reading the files recursively from subfolders with

```r
readLAScatalog("ParentFolder/", reccursive = TRUE)
```

##### Cast each catalog into `sf` objects

Then use `mapview` or other packages like `leaflet`

```r
FL_LAS_List_sf = sf::st_as_sf(FL_LAS_List)
[...]
mapview::mapview(list(FL_LAS_List_sf, BC_LAS_List_NE_sf, ...))
```

Comment: The first option returns an error `unused argument (reccursive = TRUE)`.

Comment: `recursive` takes only one c